# getElementById variable + number

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```
var num = 1;
var letter = 'a' + num;
var aLetter = document.getElementById(letter);

for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    alert(aLetter.innerHTML);
    num++;
}
```

Purpose of this code is to alert the content of these html tags by order:

```
<span class="alphStyle" id="a1">a</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a2">b</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a3">c</span> ...
```

But it only alerts the first tags content, and doesn't go further.

Why is that?

Comment: You're incrementing `num` in the loop, but `letter` AND `aLetter` will still hold the same value. You need to put the variables inside your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope

You updating `num++` has no effect as its never being used again, its outside the scope of that loop.

Try something like this instead:

```js
var num = 1;
for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    alert(document.getElementById('a' + num).innerHTML);
    num++;
}
```

```html
<span class="alphStyle" id="a1">a</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a2">b</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a3">c</span>
```

Or even

```js
var num = 1;
for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    alert(document.getElementById('a' + num++).innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<span class="alphStyle" id="a1">a</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a2">b</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a3">c</span>
```

Or even

```js
for (var num = 1; num < 4; num++) {
    alert(document.getElementById('a' + num).innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<span class="alphStyle" id="a1">a</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a2">b</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a3">c</span>
```

Or even

```js
var el;
for (var num = 1; num < 4; num++) {
    el = document.getElementById('a' + num);
    alert(el.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<span class="alphStyle" id="a1">a</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a2">b</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a3">c</span>
```

Im sure you can see the patterns here. There are many articles out there on the logic behind this, its a very simple concept though and your learning resources should be great to help you (or general google search).

https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/

Always look for working code doing anything remotely similar first, then ask yourself what they are doing different?

And keep your search general, this question should be called "looping with increment, not working when calling alert". Then you would find results matching this when you search (BEFORE posting)

Comment: @bleatinterteiment - Great, included examples to help you see other possibilities, please remember to upvote and accept answer so this moves to right area :)

Answer (score 1):

You declare aLetter outside the scope.

You need to update him in with the incremented variable x.

```
var letter;
var aLetter;
for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    letter = 'a' + x;
    aLetter = document.getElementById(letter);
    alert(aLetter.innerHTML);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the element just once.. update your code like this.

```
var num = 1;
var letter;
var aLetter;

for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    letter = 'a' + num;
    aLetter = document.getElementById(letter);
    alert(aLetter.innerHTML);
    num++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move:

```
var letter = 'a' + num;
var aLetter = document.getElementById(letter);
```

Inside the for or their value wont be changed ^^

```js
var num = 1;

for (var x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
    var letter = 'a' + num;
    var aLetter = document.getElementById(letter);
    alert(aLetter.innerHTML);
    num++;
}
```

```html
<span class="alphStyle" id="a1">a</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a2">b</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a3">c</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic in the program has to be changed to get alert for all html tags:

```
var num = 1;
var letter = 'a' + num;
var aLetter = document.getElementById(letter);

for (var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    alert(aLetter.innerHTML);
    num++;
    letter = 'a' + num;
    aLetter = document.getElementById(letter);
}
```

Please make sure num doesn't exceed the no of HTML tags and this can be controlled with x in 'for loop'.

Answer (score 1):

In your code `aLetter` ref to the same document element. Do the `getElementById` instruction inside the `for` loop. Additionally the `num` var is redundant because the `for` var `x` can made the same job.

```js
for (var x = 1; x < 4; x++) {
    var aLetter = document.getElementById('a' + x);
    alert(aLetter.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<span class="alphStyle" id="a1">a</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a2">b</span>
<span class="alphStyle" id="a3">c</span>
```